# ¿Qué significa "xunca" en la canción "La Llorona"?

Tags: significado, méxico, letras-de-canciones, significado-en-contexto

Encontré una [versión de La Llorona de Chavela Vargas en Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yxYh1DbaPA) que empieza de este modo:

> No sé que tienen las flores, Llorona,
> las flores del camposanto.
> No sé que tienen las flores, Llorona,
> las flores del camposanto.
> Que cuando las mueve el viento, Llorona,
> parece que están llorando.
> Que cuando las mueve el viento, Llorona,
> parece que están llorando.
>
> **Ay de mí, Llorona,
>
> Llorona, tú eres mi xunca.
>
> Ay de mí, Llorona,
>
> Llorona, tú eres mi xunca.**
>
> Me quitarán de quererte, Llorona,
> pero de olvidarte, nunca.
> Me quitarán de quererte, Llorona,
> pero de olvidarte, nunca.
>
> [...]

¿Qué significa "xunca"? Y en particular, ¿qué significa en el contexto de la canción?

No encontré una entrada en el Diccionario de la RAE, pero sí existe una para ["xuncu" en el diccionario de americanismos](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=xunca):

> xuncu. (Del zapoteca).
> I.    1.  m. Mx. p.u. Adolescente, joven. rur.
> 2.  Mx. p.u. Último hijo de una familia. rur.

Teniendo en cuenta el origen zapoteca de la palabra y de la leyenda de La Llorona, asumo que xunca es el femenino de xuncu y significa "mujer joven".

Pero en el contexto de la canción, la palabra xunca parece ir más allá que para describir a una mujer joven. ¿Tiene algún significado más? (p.e. querida, prometida o esposa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Veo que normalmente se escribe ***chunca***, no *xunca*. En [la entrada de wikipedia sobre la canción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Llorona_(song)) lo traducen como *sweetheart*.

El Diccionario de americanismos recoge [*chunca*](https://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=G3ecJYzhex0Awcxr6Vg%7CNxef7B1MLx0AZqGnwS2) pero con entradas propias de Argentina, Colombia y El Salvador con significados diferentes.

Ahora bien, Wikcionario sí parece darnos una buena pista en [su entrada](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chunca) al relacionarla con su origen Zapoteco istmeño y definirla como:

> Adjetivo. 1. La más pequeña de la familia

Tal y como comentas en la pregunta, este origen zapoteco istmeño parece bastante acorde con el lugar de procedencia de la canción, que al ser un [son istmeño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_istme%C3%B1o) se define como *género musical que se cultiva en el istmo de Tehuantepec, en el oriente del estado mexicano de Oaxaca*.

Por todo ello, **el significado de *chunca* en el contexto de la canción La Llorona sería el de *pequeñita* en un apelativo cariñoso a la persona a la que se refiere**. En este caso, la mujer que sufre de dolor.

Por cierto, sin desmerecer a la de la gran Chavela, de entre las muchas versiones de la canción, yo de momento me quedo con la que hizo DePedro con Fuel Fandango hace un par de años.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, si se quiere un análisis más riguroso de una palabra en una canción, creo que la pregunta debería moverse al sitio [musicfans.se] pues ya sale de lo lingüístico para adentrarse en las mentes de los autores, sus biografías y demás cosas que bien conocerán en ese otro sitio.

Comment: ¿Se pronuncia como "junca? Sé que el "x" en Español del período colonial se usaba para representar fonemas del náhuatl que hoy equivalen a la "j", y se retienen en palabras de tal origen, sobre todo en nombres de lugares mejicanos (México mismo, e.g.). De eso se presume que  sería como "j". Pero el origen en Zapoteca, de familia completamente distinta de la de Náhua, y las dos  ortografías  ("x" vs "ch") sugieren que se deriva de un fonema zapoteco que no corresponde bién al castellano. Es un poco lejos de la pregunta original, pero quedo con curiosidad.

Comment: @cuevero escuchando a Chavela Vargas cantándolo [en este momento exacto](https://youtu.be/5yxYh1DbaPA?t=80) yo apuesto por un sonido `/ʃ/` (el `/sh/` inglés). Todo lo que comentas daría para una espléndida pregunta, te animo a formularla.